# Why is the question 14573 closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

After [the question 14573](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14573/who-has-the-authority-to-assign-successor-caliph-god-prophetpeople) was asked, it became onhold by one of the mods and commented by him as such:
[image]

So I edited the question as it was commented. But, it was **"Closed"** after a while!
Why was it closed? Wht's the exact problem with this question?

Comment: For every one else, the question is open now. Good thing!

Answer (score 2):

I'm reading through the edited question right now; all the edit added was that you're looking for answers "from the perspective of Islam (both shia and sunni)", which is really no less vague than the original question.  As my comment stated, [you'll get *very* different answers](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1021/22) depending on which flavour of "Islam" the answerer is coming from.  And that's not even getting into the fact that you basically open by answering your own question when you state that "According to noble Quranm, God may assign the caliph."

The question looks, at best, to be an opening for a discussion topic, which is not what the Stack Exchange model is for.  At worst, it looks like an attempt at shoehorning polemic into a model that was never built for it.

Either way, as phrased the question is *highly* subjective, and it's still very much not clear what you're actually asking.  What exactly do you expect in an answer?  Who do you expect an answer from?  Who do you expect this answer to be useful to?  What exactly is the [practical, answerable question based on an actual problem that you face](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)?

To prevent people from wasting both their time and yours by writing answers that you're not actually looking for, you need to make it clear in your question what you actually *want* in an answer.

Comment: It is now edited!